# Vue.js: How to open external links in already opened tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, push-notification, vue.js, single-page-application

I am building an SPA using Vue.js 2. The app sends emails containing links to the app and push notifications to users from time to time.

Now, when the user click on links in the email or click on the push notification a new tab is opened with the given url.

Since the app is an SPA, I want new links to be opened in the already opened tab if exists any and don't open a second one.

links that I send to users look like this (if this can help):

```
https://app.com/#/user/123456789
```

How can I do that, is it something related to the app code, to the browser or to the links I am sending ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this sort of behavior is determined by the browser, rather than by web applications, so I don't believe this is possible. A browser extension, on the other hand, could probably achieve this.

Comment: @B.Fleming thanks for your comment .. so because it is browser related as you have said, there is no way to do it in my app and give all the users the same experience ?

Answer (score 0):

The body you send to your user should be in HTML and it should use the default target by the `a` tag (`_self`).

For example

```
<a href="https://app.com/#/user/123456789" target="_self"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://app.com/#/user/123456789"></a>
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, it works on the browser openning the link in the same tab .. but for external link the browser can not detect if a tab is already opened or not and always open a new tab for that .. thanks for your answer anyway